# Javascript Acrobat Form Dropdown Values

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, for-loop, acrobat

I have a PDF form combo box in 3 different spots. They all have 3 possible values:
1. Blank
2. Role
3. Understudy Role

If Role is selected in any of the three, I need to show the role placeholder boxes. If Understudy Role is selected in any of the three, I need to show the Understudy role radio buttons. If Role is selected twice and Understudy is selected once, then both layers need to be shown.
[Role_Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QpO1.jpg)
[Understudy Role_Selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybhCg.jpg)

I need all three combo boxes to talk to each other. The Javascript I have in comboBox 1 is:

```
//This shows/hides the fields
if (event.value == " ")
{
this.getField("1 Performance Engagement Length").display = display.hidden;
this.getField("1 Performance Fee").display = display.hidden;
this.getField("1 Total Performance Fee").display = display.hidden;
this.getField("Type of Fee").display = display.hidden;
}
else if (event.value == "Role")
{
this.getField("1 Performance Engagement Length").display = display.visible;
this.getField("1 Performance Fee").display = display.visible;
this.getField("1 Total Performance Fee").display = display.visible;
this.getField("Type of Fee").display = display.hidden;
}
else if (event.value == "Understudy Role")
{
this.getField("1 Performance Engagement Length").display = display.hidden;
this.getField("1 Performance Fee").display = display.hidden;
this.getField("1 Total Performance Fee").display = display.hidden;
this.getField("Type of Fee").display = display.visible;
}
```

This only works for comboBox 1. How can I get them all dynamically to show the right layers.
Thanks.

Comment: Because you're using event.value, the script will only get triggered when that particular dropdown is changed. Your script as shown, doesn't take into account the value of the other dropdown fields, only the one that was acted on. You've got the right idea but you haven't shown the names of the dropdown fields so I can 't give you the exact code to fix it.

Comment: @joelgeraci the names of my 3 dropdown fields are: 1a Performer type, 1b Performer type, 1c Performer type. I was trying to incorporate in the javascript for 1a Performer type, 1b Performer type value's, as the other two effect 1a Performer type. Thanks.

Comment: Can you upload the PDF somewhere?

Comment: @joelgeraci https://wetransfer.com/downloads/68dca902a60d4fbf9be8ec5e7f9327e620170425190410/7a045b thanks

Comment: I've looked at the form. If I were creating this for a customer, I'd rethink the whole approach. I'd have the visibility of the show/hide fields be determined by some document level variable and the dropdowns set that variable. You've over-complicated the logic by trying to calculate the visibiliy based on each dropdown change event when the visibility is determined by the values in all three.

Comment: @joelgeraci, thanks for the feedback. So to understand, you recommend to have a check box at the start role and underperformer role? and those would show the right boxes below? Can you explain what you mean by document level variable and the dropdowns set that variable? Thanks

Comment: Sure - you'd add a very short document level script that was... say... var understudy = false; That gets loaded when the document opens. You then have a script in all three dropdowns that sets understudy to true if understudy gets selected. Then you'd have a hidden calculated field that controls the visibility of the fields that need to be hidden or shown based on the value of understudy. When understudy is true, the fields appear, when false, the fields get hidden.